# Exceptions while calculating gpa

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception, numberformatexception

I am still new to java and my assignment for school this week has me at a loss at the moment.  Here is the assignment: Your assignment is to read the student.dat data file. First, review the attached program called
Warning.java file. The program reads a file of student academic credit data. Each line of the
input file will contain the student name (a single String with no spaces), the number of
semester hours earned (an integer), and the total quality points earned (a double).
Using the Warning.java file as the starter code for this assignment, add the following:

1. Add the code to calculate the gpa.
2. Display the name if the gpa is less than 2.0.
3. Test to ensure the output is accurate.
4. Add code to catch the following exceptions:
   • A FileNotFoundException if the input file does not exist.
   • A NumberFormatException if it can’t parse an int or double when it tries to – this
   indicates an error in the input file format. Display the record number in error.

So the warning.java file I was given has comments in it about where our code should go and that is what is confusing me.  Here is the code I have so far:

enter code here:

```
 //   Warning.java                                                  Java Foundations
 // 
//   Reads student data from a text file and writes data to another text file.
 // ****************************************************************************

 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class warning
 {
   public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException
    {
       int creditHrs = 0;         // number of semester hours earned
      double qualityPts = 0;     // number of quality points earned
      double gpa = 0;            // grade point (quality point) average
      String name = null;
      grade report = new grade(); //I created a class called but I feel it is unnecessary. 
  
  
     // Set up scanner to input file
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new 
 File("C:\\Users\\patti\\Desktop\\Patricksdcom101class\\CSIT 210\\students.dat"));
     
        System.out.println ("\n   Students on Academic Warning:\n");
        
     // Process the input file, one token at a time

     while (inFile.hasNext())
     {
        // Get the credit hours and quality points and
        // determine if the student is on warning. If so,
        // display the student's name.
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           
            name = inFile.next();
            creditHrs = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
            qualityPts = Double.parseDouble(inFile.next());
             
        //  Insert gpa calculation 
        //  and statement to determine if the student name is listed.
            gpa = qualityPts/creditHrs;
            
    if (gpa < 2.0) {
        
        gpa = qualityPts/creditHrs;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
        System.out.println(name +"\t" + df.format(gpa));
    }
     }
        inFile.close();
     //insert catch statements
     try {
      File file = new File("g:\\students.dat");
      
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
     }
    catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Invalid, file does not exist please try again");
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
        
        x.printStackTrace();
        
    }


    }

    }
```

I am trying to get the number format exception to work for me, I have the file not found exception there but I feel like I did it wrong.  The comment section that says: "Get the credit hours and quality points and determine if the student is on warning. If so, display the student's name." What I can't figure out is when I put anything in that while loop like a system.out.println statement, the ouput loops that string along with the information from the file.  The instructions make it sound like I am suppose to take user input for the credit hours and quality points right?  I would be eternally grateful to all of you if you can assist me in making my program come together.

Thank You and Have a Marvelous Day,

Patrick

Comment: As you say, if you put a println within the `while` loop, you'll get it printed out multiple times - one for each line within the file. At least how I'm reading the instructions, you shouldn't need to accept anything from the user - all the data you need is within the file. To help you out with the catch statements - A `FileNotFound` exception can happen anywhere you _read_ from a file, and a `NumberFormat` exception can happen anywhere you attempt to change something from a `String` (what they are in the file) into a number. That's a bit vague on purpose because... homework :)

Comment: that makes more sense on the while loop and scanner part.  I tend to overthink all these assignments.  As far as the exceptions go, I added two try-catch statements at the end of my code one for the FileNotFound exception and the other for the NumberFormat exception.  So my output looks like this:                                     Students on Academic Warning:

Jones 1.35
Walker 1.9
Street 1.739
Davis 1.8
Summers 1.6

Invalid, file: g:\students.dat does not exist

Number Format Exception error
Is this what the output of the exceptions are suppose to look like?

Comment: I would assume that you're supposed to put the exceptions in the proper areas of the code (and not at the end of the code). So where do you open a file in the normal flow of the code? Where do you transform a string into an int in the normal flow of the code? That's where the try/catch blocks should be.

Comment: see that's why I feel I have done these exceptions wrong.  In the comments, right after I close the file, it says to start our try-catch statements there.  We have another assignment to do and I think I should move onto that one and wait to get her feedback cause all of the instructions and comments in the code were extremely confusing.  Thank you for all your help with this, I really appreciate it.